# need help with BTC transfer

Tags: wallet, json-rpc, network, testnet, fraud

All,

I received some BTC to my coinbase wallet after someone asked me to setup custom network using the below setting. I received the BTC but I couldn't transfer to any other wallet and the says invalid BTC address. Am I scammed?
Network name: Bitcoin
RPC URL: https://testnet-rpc.satoshichain.io
Chain ID: 5758
Currency Symbol: BTC
Block Explorer URL: https://www.blockchain.com/explorer

Any help is much appreciated. The person who sent me this wants me to send money so he can validate the wallet address.

Is this true?

I don't know a lot about these so please help.

Thanks